# Playing video slow and lag when using AndroidFFmpeg

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-video-player

I am building an app using AndroidFFmpeg(https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg).

With medium `file` `size(<100MB)`, the `player` works well. But with the large file `size(from 100MB)` or `HD video` format, the video is so slow and lag, not sync with `audio`, the `audio` is break.

Can anyone know this issue, please help me. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> both video files were created with the same codecs?

This is very important, because you will experiment an annoying lag if some videos has codecs that are not supported.

In android i have the standard for codecs:

> H.264 for video.
>
> AAC for audio.

Comment: Yes. Both video files have H.264 for video and AAC for audio.